# Do small plants damage PVC pipes?

Tags: gardening

I have the drainage pipes (100mm diameter)from the gutters about 5 to 15 cm (2 to 6 in) below ground level. I want to plant small flowering plants above this area. Is it safe? Can small plants damage PVC drainage pipes?

Comment: Tree roots are more of an issue with regard to drainage pipes than small flowering plants would ever be.